# spring authentication with Embedded Ldap

Tags: spring, authentication, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to integrate spring authentication with embedded ldap.

I have user info in local ldif file.

User1

```
 dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword
```

User 2

```
dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword
```

Spring WebsecurityConfigFile

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                    .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
   }
}
```

**userDnPattern** in config file I have taken ou=people (uid={0},ou=people) so I'm able to authenticate **bob**.
When it comes to **joe** his directory path is different.
So I'm not able to login using joe's username and password.

[image]

What should be my SpringConfiguration for authenticating all the users irrespective of the directory structure?

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832238/2529954) answers your question.

Comment: Yeah using userSearchFilter I'm able to get all users.

Comment: Then you can close this post and leave a vote on the other one ;)

Comment: I'm adding spring configuration, if It doesn't add any value then will close the issue.

Comment: You can then accept the answer for others to find it more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication for any user in the DIT (Directory information tree) using **userSearchFilter**.

Spring configuration is,

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                    .contextSource()
                        .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                        .and()
                    .passwordCompare()        
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
```

Thanks @EricLavault